# dpkg: error processing file in archives

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, repository, backtrack

When I want to upgrade the backtrack linux to ubuntu 14.04 the following errror occurs:

```
(Reading database ... 218798 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace hostname 3.03ubuntu1 (using .../hostname_3.15ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement hostname ...
dpkg-deb: file `/var/cache/apt/archives/hostname_3.15ubuntu1_amd64.deb' contains ununderstood data member data.tar.xz     , giving up
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/hostname_3.15ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/hostname_3.15ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix it?
Note: I copied the ubuntu repos to bactrack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't upgrade Kali(backtracks' new name) to Ubuntu. Kali is Debian Testing based.

Comment: How should I fix problem when I want to install packaged? it isn't possible

Comment: You need to delete all Ubuntu releated repos.

Comment: When I want to install packages in backtrack it shows me error fetching to repos.... So I deleted backtrack repos and copied my ubuntu repos

Comment: Download new counter part of backtrack: http://www.kali.org/

Comment: Thank you I think I should get rid of my backtrack.. tahnks :|